# scrollspy de materialize

Tags: html, css, materialize

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>
      <main>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 m12 l12" style='background-image:url("img/img.jpg"); background-size: cover; height: 700px'>
            
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 m9 l10">
              <div id="introduction" class="section scrollspy">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea</p>
              </div>

              <div id="structure" class="section scrollspy">
                <p> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
              </div>

              <div id="initialization" class="section scrollspy">
                <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col hide-on-small-only m3 l2">
              <ul class="section table-of-contents">
                <li><a href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
                <li><a href="#structure">Structure</a></li>
                <li><a href="#initialization">Intialization</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
      <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.scrollspy').scrollSpy();
         });
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Buenas amigos!

Estoy maquetando una página con la plataforma Materialize. En la parte de la derecha quiero poner una tabla de contenidos, al igual que en la página de la documentación de dicha plataforma:

http://materializecss.com/scrollspy.html

Mi problema es el siguiente: no logo hacer que toda la tabla de contenidos se desplace como lo hace en la página de materialize.

He probado a poner la misma en un div con una posicion: fixed, pero tampoco me ha dado resultado, ya que toma como posición el primer "row" de la estructura y no el suyo propio.

Mi estructura es la siguiente:

```
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
    //contenido
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col s12 m9 l9">
     //contenido
   </div>
   <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
    //tabla de contenidos
      <ul class="section table-of-contents" >
        <li><a href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
        <li><a href="#structure">Structure</a></li>
        <li><a href="#initialization">Intialization</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Muchas gracias! ^^

Comment: Hola IreneA, deberías crear un [mcve] para que podamos ver el problema. Si editas la pregunta, hay un icono que te permite crear un snippet de código (incluye las dependencias como Materialize, etc.) que podemos ejecutar.

Comment: Ya he subido un snipet, espero que me podáis echar un cable, saludos! y gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código que tienes está bien. Quitando las partes innecesarias y añadiendo una referencia correcta a jQuery y scrollSpy ya funciona.

Lo único que te faltaría sería hacer que el menú se quede fijo de manera relativa al su contenedor en lugar de la pantalla. En Materialize eso se consigue con [`pushpin`](http://materializecss.com/pushpin.html). Le tienes que indicar a partir de qué posición de la ventana quieres que se haga `fixed` y mientras tanto será `relative` dándole el efecto que buscas.

Entonces sólo tendrías que añadir esto en tu JS:

```
  $(".toc-wrapper").pushpin({
    top: 700 /* la altura del row anterior, para que no se superponga */
  });
```

Y aquí lo puedes ver funcionando (tienes que darle a ver en página completa):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.scrollspy').scrollSpy();
  
  $(".toc-wrapper").pushpin({
    top: $(".toc-wrapper").offset().top
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<!--Import materialize.css-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->

<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m12 l12" style='background-image:url("http://lorempixel.com/700/700/cats"); background-size: cover; height: 700px'>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m9 l10">
        <div id="introduction" class="section scrollspy">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
            velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea</p>
        </div>

        <div id="structure" class="section scrollspy">
          <p> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
            ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
            mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="initialization" class="section scrollspy">
          <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
            in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
            fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
            magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
            occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
            in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col hide-on-small-only m3 l2">
        <div class="toc-wrapper" style="top:0px">
          <ul class="section table-of-contents">
            <li><a href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
            <li><a href="#structure">Structure</a></li>
            <li><a href="#initialization">Intialization</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Gracias!  
En esta parte del código: 

$(".toc-wrapper").pushpin({
    top: 700
  });

¿Podría calcular el alto de la pantalla del usuario para introducirla en el valor del top?

Comment: @IreneA Claro, yo he usado 700 directamente porque sabía el valor, pero realmente lo correcto sería añadir algo que la calcule automáticamente. De ese modo, si el contenido que hay por encima cambia, el posicionamiento `fixed` seguirá funcionando correctamente. Esto lo puedes hacer usando algo como `$(elemento).offset().top`; he editado la respuesta para que lo puedas ver funcionando